# Xamarin.Forms Image Source binding to string (MVVM)

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am intending to bind the source for an image from a URL I am loading in my ViewModel

In the xaml file, it works just fine if I use:

`<Image Source="https://example.com/image.jpg"/>`

However, it won't work if I use

ViewModel

```
public string Image = {get; set;}    
Image = "https://example.com/image.jpg";
```

XAML - I am setting the BindingContext to the ViewModel

`<Image Source="{Binding Image}"/>`

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: are you setting the value to the property **before** you are assigning the BindingContext?

Comment: I believe I am. I am manipulating other properties at the same stage and they are bindings to their peers correctly. Also, in debug mode, if I leave the pointer over the property in the xaml file, it shows me the string is there. I’ve tried changing it from string to ImageSource but it also hasn’t worked

Comment: Supposed to be `public string Image {get; set;} ` (no "=")? Have you tried `public string Image => "https://example.com/image.jpg"`?

Comment: The “=“ was a typo. I’ll try your suggestion and report back

Answer (score 1):

The code below should work. I set the binding in Xaml.

Xaml:

```
  <ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <local:ViewModel></local:ViewModel>
</ContentPage.BindingContext>
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout>
        <Image Source="{Binding Image}"></Image>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

ViewModel:

```
 public class ViewModel
{
    public string Image { get; set; }
    public ViewModel()
    {
        Image = "https://aka.ms/campus.jpg"; //"https://example.com/image.jpg"
    }

}
```

Or you could set the binding in code behind:

Xaml:

```
 <ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout>
        <Image Source="{Binding Image}"></Image>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Code behind:

```
 public partial class Page2 : ContentPage
{
    public Page2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.BindingContext = new ViewModel();
    }
}
public class ViewModel
{
    public string Image { get; set; }
    public ViewModel()
    {
        Image = "https://aka.ms/campus.jpg"; //"https://example.com/image.jpg"
    }

}
```